# Why std::uppercase doesn't work with strings?

Tags: c++, manipulators

I've been using manipulators for some time without fully understand how they work.

This code:

```
std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase;
std::cout << std::uppercase << 77 << '\n';
std::cout << std::nouppercase << 77 << '\n';
```

Or alternatively this:

```
std::cout << std::hex;
std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::showbase | std::ios::uppercase) << 77 << '\n';
std::cout << std::nouppercase << 77 << '\n';
```

Both outputs this:

```
0X4D // 'X' and 'D' uppercase
0x4d // 'x' and 'd' lowercase
```

However none of the following lines of code can convert the string "abcd" to uppercase. Why?

```
std::cout << std::uppercase << "abcd" << '\n';
std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::uppercase) << "abcd" << '\n';
```

Another question is why `showbase` and `uppercase` must be qualified with `std::ios::` inside `std::setiosflags()` and only with `std::` outside that function?

Finaly, why `std::hex` can't be accepted inside `std::setiosflags()`

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the documentation for [`std::uppercase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/uppercase).

> Enables the use of uppercase characters in floating-point and hexadecimal integer output.

`std::ios_base::hex` is accepted by `std::setiosflags` there is an example in the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setiosflags).

Here is the example for `std::uppercase`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase
              << "0x2a with uppercase: " << std::uppercase << 0x2a << '\n'
              << "0x2a with nouppercase: " << std::nouppercase << 0x2a << '\n'
              << "1e-10 with uppercase: " << std::uppercase << 1e-10 << '\n'
              << "1e-10 with nouppercase: " << std::nouppercase << 1e-10 << '\n';
}
```

Here is the example for `std::setiosflags`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout <<  std::resetiosflags(std::ios_base::dec) 
              <<  std::setiosflags(  std::ios_base::hex
                                   | std::ios_base::uppercase
                                   | std::ios_base::showbase) << 42 << '\n';
}
```

The definitions:

`std::hex` is defined as `std::ios_base& hex( std::ios_base& str );`

`std::ios_base::hex` is defined as `static constexpr fmtflags hex = /*...*/;`

Answer (score 2):

`std::uppercase` only affects the result of conversion to hex.

`std::hex` is a manipulator object, while [`setiosflags`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setiosflags) expects an integer formed by combining individual bits. Or, more precisely, a type behaving in that manner. Instead of `std::hex` (which is of the wrong type) you can use `std::ios_base::hex`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add my 2 cents. I write at the beginning of my code this 2 lines to make life a bit easier:

```
const long base = std::ios::showbase;
const long upper = std::ios::uppercase;
```

And later use the constants instead of the tedious code.